# Câmera do Personagem não move!

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estou fazendo um tutorial do Unity que baixei na Asset Store no seguinte link https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21028

Tentei fazer meu personagem girar para olhar em direção ao mouse, mas ele não consegue rotacionar, e só olha para frente no caso e não consigo faze-lo olhar para os outros lugares, como por exemplo o canto direito, esquerdo, trás do personagem, somente em linha reta! 
Uso a função `Turning()` para cuidar da rotação.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 6f;
    Vector3 movement;
    Animator anim;
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;
    int floorMask;
    float camRayLenght = 100f;

    void Awake(){
        floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");
        Move (h, v);
        Turning ();
        Animating (h, v);
    }

    void Move(float h,float v){
        //tertemina o movimento
        movement.Set(h,0f,v);
        //normaliza o movimento
        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        // efetua o movimento
        playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);
    }

    //girar o jogador
    void Turning(){
        Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit floorHit;

        if (Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, camRayLenght, floorMask)) {

            Vector3 playerToMouse=floorHit.point-transform.position;
            playerToMouse.y=0f;
            // rotaçao do personagem
            Quaternion newRotation= Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
        }
    }

    void Animating(float h,float v){
        bool walking = h != 0f || v!=0f;
        anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", walking);
    }
}
```

Inspector do Player - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc0m5.png
[image: Inspector do Player]

Inspector do Floor - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnOOs.png
[image: Inspector do Floor]

Comment: @DerpPlayss, a câmera está funcionando direito? Mudar o  Floor resolveu tudo? Existe mais algum problema?

Comment: @Nils Fique a vontade para postar uma resposta agora :) **Excelente** a sua iniciativa de incentivar os seus inscritos [a virem aqui tirarem dúvidas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbPVwr3Wqxw). Obrigado por compartilhar o site com eles.

Comment: @Qmechanic73 Eu que agradeço ao stackoverflow e sua comunidade, eu aprendi muito vindo aqui e a estrutura para resolver dúvidas coletivamente é sensacional. E algumas semanas atrás eu vi que agora dá para tirar dúvida de quase tudo(tem área para tudo).

Answer (score 7):

O problema está no teu objeto Floor(Quad).

Quanto você usar um Raycast saindo da câmera em

```
void Turning(){
    ...
    if (Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, camRayLenght, floorMask)) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Você passa como parâmetro o `floorMask`

Que é instanciado em

```
void Awake(){
    floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");
    ..
}
```

Isso quer dizer que o raio que sai da câmera vai procurar um Layer chamado "Floor", mais ou menos como esse diagrama.

[image: Diagrama do Raycast da câmera]

Se ele não encontrar nenhum objeto com o Layer marcado como Floor ele não vai entrar no teu `if`e não vai realizar o código que faz o personagem girar.

Você quando eu vi a captura de tela do Inspector do teu chão, ele está marcado como Default, você pode mudar ele para "Floor" - Se não houver, basta criar um. Que deve resolver

[image: Layer_Floor]

Portanto, toda vez que você trabalhar com Layers(ou Tags) em código no Unity, vale a pena verificar se os objetos estão configurados corretamente, ou se o nome está igual(maiúsculas e minusculas são diferenciadas).
E quando for usar um Raycast, verifique também se as coordenadas estão passando pelos pontos desejados. Pois as vezes ele pode não tocar em nenhum objeto com o Layer marcado, então é bom verificar se a origem está certa (no caso a Câmera) e se a direção está correta (pega a partir do mouse).